# Average of multiple data frames in R having same column pattern

Tags: r, average

I have multiple data frames or files which i would like to get the average of columns in each data-frame and write them back.

The pattern across all my dataframes. So this is how all my files are named their column header.

```
names(WGCNA_avg_gene)
 [1] "Family"    "Symbol"    "C1_S1_S7"  "C1_S3_S9"  "C2_S1_S10" "C2_S2_S11" "C3_S1_S13" "C3_S2_S14" "C3_S3_S15"
[10] "C4_S1_S16" "C4_S2_S17" "C4_S3_S18" "C5_S1_S19" "C5_S2_S20" "C5_S3_S21" "C6_S1_S22" "C6_S2_S23" "C6_S3_S24"
```

Now so far what im doing is this way

```
WGCNA_avg_gene  <- e %>% mutate(C1 = rowMeans(.[grep("C1", names(.))]), 
                                C2 = rowMeans(.[grep("C2", names(.))]),
                                C3 = rowMeans(.[grep("C3", names(.))]),
                                C4 = rowMeans(.[grep("C4", names(.))]),
                                C5 = rowMeans(.[grep("C5", names(.))]),
                                C6 = rowMeans(.[grep("C6", names(.))]))

names(WGCNA_avg_gene)

one = WGCNA_avg_gene %>% select(Family,Symbol,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6)
names(one)[2] = "Gene"
```

Im getting average of each data frame subletting it and then write back.

The steps which needs to be done after reading and what i understood is this.

- Read all the files from a folder
- Make them into a list.
- The use function into the list lappply perhaps.

But I can read the files and get a list but im not sure how to apply my above average which I'm calculating for individual data-frame into my list and do the same.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List all the files that you want to read with `list.files`, use `lapply` to read each one divide them into different groups based on column name and take mean of each one of them.

```
list_of_files <- list.files('csv/folder/',pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)

lapply(list_of_files, function(x) {
    tmp <- read.csv(x)
    t1 <- tmp[-(1:2)]
    cbind(tmp[1:2], sapply(split.default(t1, 
          sub('_.*', '', names(t1))), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE))
}) -> result
```

If you want to write the result back to a new dataframe for each file.

```
lapply(list_of_files, function(x) {
  tmp <- read.csv(x)
  t1 <- tmp[-(1:2)]
  result <- cbind(tmp[1:2], sapply(split.default(t1, 
                   sub('_.*', '', names(t1))), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE))
  write.csv(result, paste0('result_', basename(x)), row.names = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: works absolutely fine .now Im trying to write back the result by this [for(i in 1:length(result)){
  results = as.data.frame(result[[i]])
  write.table(results,file=paste0(i,"a_"),sep = "\t",quote = FALSE,row.names = FALSE,col.names = TRUE)
}]   . How do the save the result by the name you have read it from the folder ..right now i use a prefix "a_" i would like to save them as the same name i read them is that possible?

Comment: See updated answer. This would write all the files with `result_` filename in your working directory.

Comment: airways saw your answers and now today right in action

Comment: how to support you apart from using paypal ..big fan of your answers ..since i dont have paypal..anyother ways to show my support for you?

Comment: "I am glad that my answers were helpful to you." i would have invested few days to figure out this but still coudnn't might come up with the answer you gave..as biologist my programming skills are pretty naive..i look for ways which can give me right answer and sometimes due to lack of my programming skills i have to take the longer route.